# How to use TabLayout in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I'm trying to create app with layout floating up from bottom of screen, but I have tabs on bottom of screen, so I want to hide them with animation of layout floating up. My question is how to get access to that tab layout which is in other xml file than RelativeLayout which is used already in animation. I have TabLayout defined also in other file than I use for animation. 
My xml files looks like that 
FragmentsActivity :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.young.howittastes.FragmentsActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:background="#d8d8d8"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And Home Fragment :

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerlayout">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="animation"
        android:id="@+id/animationButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:id="@+id/commentLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:elevation="6dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WRITE"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="READ"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#030303"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment has classes onCreateView and ContentAdapter.
TabLayout is defined like that, but it's defined in other file than Fragment in which I use animation :

```
TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new HomeContent(), "Home");
        adapter.addFragment(new FavoritesContent(), "Favorite");
        adapter.addFragment(new FavoritesContent(), "Search");
        adapter.addFragment(new FavoritesContent(), "Write");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to include one of your layout XML layout files within the other.  If that is correct you use the `<include>` tag within the enclosing layout.  For example if tabbar.xml is the layout you want to include:

```
<include layout="@layout/tabbar"/>
```

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) for more details.

Comment: If I will make other xml file for tabbar only and include it in both xml files it's not working, if I will include it only in xml file which is handling fragments and make second View to define it in java file it's not working and without second View it's not working neither.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?  And what do you mean by the "second View"?  And when you say "java file" are you referring to an XML layout file?